# Is it possible to vectorize the solution here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ode

Please note that I am very new to python. I have never taken a programming course and I am self teaching when it comes to python, so excuse my verbiage or lack of proficient code.

I have am having trouble trying to vectorize the calculations with respect to the parameters. As you can see, some of my parameter values are arrays that take on multiple values. I looked into vectorizing my results, but again, being fairly new I am unsure how to do that. Any guidance on how I could vectorize the results would be helpful. If there is a more proficient way to do this, maybe 'looping over parameter values?', please share any tips. Thank you.

Below is my code followed by the error I currently get.

```
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def ode(t,y):
    sigma1 = 1/10
    sigma2 = 1/4
    alpha = 1/10.4
    gamma = 1/5
    beta = 0.4
    f = np.array([0.111, 0.111, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.175, 0.175, 0.287, 0.287, 0.287, 0.287, 0.287])
    h = np.array([0.182, 0.055, 0.055, 0.055, 0.068, 0.068, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.512, 0.512, 0.512, 0.617])
    dh = np.array([0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0.002, 0.009, 0.009, 0.009, 0.009, 0.036, 0.036, 0.036, 0.149, 0.149, 0.149, 0.328])
    d = np.array([0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.059, 0.059, 0.059, 0.129])
    N = np.array([60000,65000,65000,65000,65000,65000,65000,65000,65000,70000,70000,60000,60000,35000,350000,20000])
    
    return np.array([-(beta*(y[2]+y[3])/N)*y[0],
                     (beta*(y[2]+y[3])/N)*y[0]-gamma*y[1],
                     f*gamma*y[1]-sigma1*y[2],
                     (1-f)*gamma*y[1]-sigma2*y[3],
                     h*sigma1*y[2]-alpha*y[4],
                     (1-h-d)*sigma1*y[2]+sigma2*y[3]+(1-dh)*alpha*y[4], 
                     d*sigma1*y[2]+dh*alpha*y[4]])

t0 = 0 
t_bound = 100 
y0 = np.array([480000,0,10000,10000,0,0,0])
sol = scipy.integrate.RK45(ode, t0, y0, t_bound)
t = []
y = []
while sol.status == "running":
    t.append(sol.t)
    y.append(sol.y)
    sol.step()

plt.plot(np.array(t), np.array(y))
plt.legend(("susceptible", "exposed","infectious_s", "infectious_a", "hospitalized", "recovered", "deaths"))
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("cases")
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
line 85, in asarray    
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: `f*gamma*y[1]-sigma1*y[2]` and `(1-f)*gamma*y[1]-sigma2*y[3]` are sequences, so you cannot use them as an elements of the array. What result were you expecting here? Perhaps [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) would be useful.

Comment: Again the question, what do the parameter arrays represent? A function table for a time dependency? Then there should be interpolation involved to get the correct value for the time parameter. // Different instances with different parameters? Then the initial value needs to be replicated accordingly, the ODE function needs to translate the flat input into instance structures and back.

Comment: @jakevdp thanks for your input. When I try that I get the error: ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated. Instead of a single solution at each time step, I am expecting a collection of solutions. Which leads me to believe I should vectorize the solution? Essentially, I want the same system of ODE's to be evaluated at all of the parameter values in the array. Maybe there is a more proficient way for me to achieve this.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your input. Essentially, it would be the same system of ODE's being evaluated at all of the parameter values in the arrays. The arrays represent different parameter values for different age groups. But it would be the exact same system of equations. Hence why I put an array for the parameter values, rather than writing the same ODE over a ridiculous amount of times. Should I loop over the parameter values instead? If so, is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: What's line 85?  Give full traceback so we can easily identify where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve several instances of the same problem simultaneously, then you need to prepare compartments for each instance in the system vector. In the code this is where the initial state is constructed.

```
y0 = y0*num_instances
```

numpy allows elementwise operations, that is, the same scalar computation can be extended to an array of arguments. To use this, one has to extract these component arrays from the state vector. One can use the reshape and transposition operations for this.

```
def ode(t,y):
    y = y.reshape([dim_state,-1]).T
    dy = np.array([-(beta*(y[2]+y[3])/N)*y[0],
                     (beta*(y[2]+y[3])/N)*y[0]-gamma*y[1],
                     f*gamma*y[1]-sigma1*y[2],
                     (1-f)*gamma*y[1]-sigma2*y[3],
                     h*sigma1*y[2]-alpha*y[4],
                     (1-h-d)*sigma1*y[2]+sigma2*y[3]+(1-dh)*alpha*y[4], 
                     d*sigma1*y[2]+dh*alpha*y[4]])
    return dy.T.flatten()
```

This should work or at least give more advanced errors.

Answer (score 0):

When using `scipy` functions like this it's a good idea to run your function with initial conditions, to verify that it produces a result that match the `scipy` expectations.

Doing that with your `ode`:

```
In [261]: ode(0,np.array([480000,0,10000,10000,0,0,0]))
<ipython-input-260-5c67294dcd97>:13: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return np.array([-(beta*(y[2]+y[3])/N)*y[0],
Out[261]: 
array([array([ -64000.        ,  -59076.92307692,  -59076.92307692,
        -59076.92307692,  -59076.92307692,  -59076.92307692,
        -59076.92307692,  -59076.92307692,  -59076.92307692,
        -54857.14285714,  -54857.14285714,  -64000.        ,
        -64000.        , -109714.28571429,  -10971.42857143,
       -192000.        ]),
       array([ 64000.        ,  59076.92307692,  59076.92307692,  59076.92307692,
        59076.92307692,  59076.92307692,  59076.92307692,  59076.92307692,
        59076.92307692,  54857.14285714,  54857.14285714,  64000.        ,
        64000.        , 109714.28571429,  10971.42857143, 192000.        ]),
       array([-1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000.,
       -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000., -1000.,
       -1000.]),
       array([-2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500.,
       -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500., -2500.,
       -2500.]),
       array([182.,  55.,  55.,  55.,  68.,  68., 139., 139., 139., 139., 251.,
       251., 251., 512., 512., 512., 617.]),
       array([3317., 3445., 3445., 3445., 3431., 3431., 3357., 3357., 3357.,
       3357., 3235., 3235., 3235., 2929., 2929., 2929., 2754.]),
       array([  1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,  14.,
        14.,  14.,  59.,  59.,  59., 129.])], dtype=object)
In [262]: _.shape
Out[262]: (7,)
```

It's a 7 element array like `y0`, but object dtype, what the warning calls a ragged array.  The `sciy` function expects a numeric dtype.

The subarrays differ in shape:

```
In [352]: [a.shape for a in _]
Out[352]: [(16,), (16,), (17,), (17,), (17,), (17,), (17,)]
```

If they were the same the result would be `(7,16)` numeric array.  It still wouldn't work, but the error would be different.  `N` is (16,), the others (17,).

Trying to convert that object dtype array to float produces the `sequence` error:

```
 np.asarray(Out[261], float)
```

As a general rule ode solvers like this can't handle multiple input conditions. Normally those `f, h, dh,...` inputs are supplied via the `args` tuple.  You can't get around the fact the `ode` must return a numeric array that matches `y0` in size.

From the RK$5 docs:

```
fun callable
Right-hand side of the system. The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is  
scalar, and there are two options for the ndarray y: It can either have shape 
(n,); then fun must return array_like with shape (n,). Alternatively it can 
have shape (n, k); then fun must return an array_like with shape (n, k), i.e., 
each column corresponds to a single column in y. The choice between the two 
options is determined by vectorized argument (see below).
```

Here the `vectorized` option means the function can be called for `k` `y` values at once.  That's not vectorizing in the `args` parameters, but rather it allows the RK45 to evaluate the `fun` at multiple points at once, hopefully speeding up the overall calc.

Change the `ode` to:

```
def ode(t,y,f,h,dh,d,N):
    ...
```

Then calling it with one element of each of these arrays should work in the solver:

```
In [364]: i=1;ode(0,np.array([480000,0,10000,10000,0,0,0]),f[i],h[i],dh[i],d[i],N[i
     ...: ])
Out[364]: 
array([-5.90769231e+04,  5.90769231e+04, -1.00000000e+03, -2.50000000e+03,
        5.50000000e+01,  3.44500000e+03,  0.00000000e+00])

args = (f[i],h[i],dh[i],d[i],N[i])
sol = scipy.integrate.RK45(ode, t0, y0, t_bound, args=args)
```